# LocationManager never gives Available status for GPS - Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I created a small app to test out the GPS features of codenameone, but found that it never give an `Available` status, only `Temporarily Unavailable`.

For my little test app, the relevant code is the following:

```
private void doRetrieveLocationAction() {
    try {
        Location location = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocation();
        taLocationDisplay.setText(getGPSDetails() + "\n : " + location.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        taLocationDisplay.setText("Error retrieving location:"
                + "\n"
                + getGPSDetails()
                + "\n " + e.getMessage());
        ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Error retrieving location:"
                + "\n"
                + getGPSDetails()
                + "\n " + e.getMessage(), 5000);
    }
}

private String getGPSDetails() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("isEnabled: ").append(LocationManager.getLocationManager().isGPSEnabled());
    sb.append("\nisGPSDetectionSupported: ").append(LocationManager.getLocationManager().isGPSDetectionSupported());
    sb.append("\ngetStatus: ").append(LocationManager.getLocationManager().getStatus());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The status being Integer, is assigned the following values in the codenameone source code:

```
public static final int AVAILABLE = 0;
public static final int OUT_OF_SERVICE = 1;
public static final int TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE = 2;
```

What I get when the GPS is off:

[image: [1]: GPS is Off]

What I get Immediately after the GPS is turned on:

[image: Immediately after GPS is turned on]

What I get after I waited a bit:

[image: GPS turned on and waited]

These results show that the Status never changes. When is the status supposed to change and how am I supposed to use that status? How do I know when the GPS can function or not?

This is being tested on `Android`

Answer (score 0):

The GPS will be off by default unless you explicitly try to get "real" location by binding a listener to location events. So what you normally get is hybrid location and not GPS location.